# Why do headlines contain articles when they shouldn't?

Tags: definite-article, headlinese

Why do we put articles in title or headings?

What difference would it make to add the articles in "A bag of cookies"  and "The bag of cookies"?

Another example:

> The affection distorts the perception.

Shouldn't it be "affection distorts perception" because it's headlinese?

**Why do we see an inclusion of articles in headlinese?**

Comment: If your question is "what is the difference between *a*, *the*, and no article at all, I think the question is too broad.  There are many, many web pages about [the use of articles in English grammar](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/).

Comment: My question is putting THE in headings.. I am reading a story which titles this "the affection distorts the perception"  can't it be affection distorts perception

Comment: What headline where? Can you add some links or screenshots showing this? Headlinese is primarily used for brevity (in the case of printed news or news summary web pages) or for impact (making bait words stand out). It is a matter of writing style, not of language itself.